# ListView Throws null pointer exception but the controller is connected to FXML

Tags: listview, javafx, fxml

My ListView Throws null pointer exception but the controller is connected to FXML. I have looked but everything looks like it is connected as far as fxml and controller. It does call the method but when it sets the listview it throws an error. I have tried many different approaches but always back at this, I don't know if there is a better way to handle this or another container I can use to hold a list?

```
package Controler;

import javafx.beans.property.ListProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleListProperty;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import wiziwig.interfaces.Language;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;


import java.util.*;

public class WiziwigContentLoader {

 Language language;

 WizigHelper helper;

 public WiziwigContentLoader() {
 }

 @FXML
 Button Create;

 @FXML
 ListView comp;


 @FXML
 ListView added;

 protected ListProperty<String> listProperty = new SimpleListProperty<>();

 public Language getLanguage() {
     return language;
 }

 public void setLanguage(Language language) {
     this.language = language;
 }
 public void getList() {
     List<String> strings = new ArrayList<>();
     strings.add("hi");
     strings.add("ME");
     listProperty.set(FXCollections.observableArrayList(strings));
     comp.setItems(listProperty);
 }

 public void setAddedComponentListView() {

 added.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(language.usedComponents));

 }
 public void create(){
     language.runFile(language.createFile());
 }

 public void setComponent(){
     comp.setOnMouseClicked((MouseEvent event)-> 
     helper.switchToProp(event,"Proproties.fxml",getLanguage()));
 }
}
```

```
  <?import javafx.scene.AmbientLight?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
  <?import javafx.scene.control.ListView?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
  <?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
 <?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>

 <AnchorPane prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.121" 
  xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
  fx:controller="Controler.WiziwigContentLoader">
<children>
   <BorderPane layoutX="2.0" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0">
      <left>

      </left>
       <top>
          <AmbientLight color="CHARTREUSE" lightOn="true" 
            BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
       </top>
      <right>
         <ListView fx:id="added" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" 
         BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
      </right>
     <bottom>
         <HBox alignment="BOTTOM_RIGHT" prefHeight="43.0" prefWidth="600.0" 
         BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <children>
               <Button fx:id="Create" mnemonicParsing="false" 
                onMouseClicked="#create" text="Create" />
            </children>
         </HBox>
     </bottom>
     <left>
        <ListView fx:id="comp" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0"  
        BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
     </left>
  </BorderPane>
 </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

StackTrace:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at Controler.WiziwigContentLoader.setBox(WiziwigContentLoader.java:56)
    at Controler.WizigHelper.switchToWIZI(WizigHelper.java:36)
    at Controler.StartWindowController.lambda$initialize$0(StartWindowController.java:36)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8413)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:394)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$353(GlassViewEventHandler.java:432)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:431)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at 
    com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$147(WinApplication.java:177)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: Post stacktrace, please.

Comment: The NullPointerException is thrown in `WiziwigContentLoader.setBox` but your provided code doesn't show this method.